# How to replace particular string from a statement in Java?

Tags: java, api

I'm trying to replace a particular string from a statement that will change dynamically based on the API response [please find the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fqnS.png)

For example : 
 "statement": "5559 AND (5563 AND (5565 AND 5564)) AND 5561"

Scenario 1:
 string to be replaced - 5565

Expected output - "statement": "5559 AND (5563 AND 5564) AND 5561"

Scenario 2:
 string to be replaced - 5563

Expected output - "statement": "5559 AND (5565 AND 5564) AND 5561"

Comment: Where's the code showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: What is the rule that determines which part has to be removed ? In scenario 1 you remove the part, but in scenario 2 you replace it. What is the rule behind that ? How to know with what the string as to be replaced in scenario 2 ? After clarifying your question, could you also put what you have tried so far and where you are stuck ?

Comment: If I understand.. you have a condition (?) represented by a tree; if a leaf matches the search-string, you remove that leaf and make a short-circuit between parent node and sibling node. Can't you simply replace search-string with `TRUE`? As alternative, you can parse the string into a tree structure and manipulate it...

Comment: I have tried based on below points
1. I had converted list items to array based on spaces
2. I had checked string contains any index value in the loop.
3. I had replaced index value and join the array values in it.

Hope it would be clear!

Answer (score 0):

The java String class has a replaceFirst method that takes two arguments: a regular expression and the string to replace for the first location that matches the expression.

In this particular example, you could then do something simple:

```
String stringToReplace = "5565";
String replacement = "5563";
String newString = existingString.replace(stringToReplace, replacement);
```

How you set those strings is up to you. I'm just demonstrating how to use the method.

But here's the fun part. Imagine that stringToReplace is 5. What you really mean is if 5 as a token appears in the string. You aren't changing ALL the 5s, only something like "AND 5 OR 3" to "AND 17 OR 3", but if you had "OR 55", you wouldn't want that to become "OR 1717", right?

So the regular expression is going to be more complicated, if you're worried about those situations.

You could make the expression " 5 " (a space before and after), but that won't work with "AND (5 OR 3)" or "AND (3 OR 5)" or even if 5 is at the beginning or end of the string.

It would take me some time to figure out the most optimal regular expression. I would recommend you to read the JavaDocs and then begin experimenting. It's going to take you some effort.

Or not worry about that part yet.